# How do I compare all objects in a collection against all objects in the same collection?

Tags: java, performance, collections, comparison

How do I compare all objects within a collection against all other objects within the same collection? I currently use a for-loop with another, nested for-loop. However, this is slow and I would like to optimise my method.

Please see below for an example. Specifically, how can I optimise the `personsGroupedByFirstName` method? The method retrieves a list of `Person` and converts it to a map where each `Person` is grouped with others with the same `firstName`.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Scratch().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        List<Person> persons = getPersons();
        Map<String, List<Person>> stacks = personsGroupedByFirstName(persons);

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Person>> entrySet : stacks.entrySet()) {
            String key = entrySet.getKey();
            List<Person> value = entrySet.getValue();

            System.out.println("First name: " + key);
            System.out.println("People: " + value);
        }
    }

    private List<Person> getPersons() {
        return List.of(
                new Person("Andrew", "Red"), new Person("Bob", "Red"),
                new Person("Craig", "Red"), new Person("Daniel", "Red"),
                new Person("Andrew", "Yellow"), new Person("Bob", "Yellow"),
                new Person("Craig", "Yellow"), new Person("Daniel", "Yellow"),
                new Person("Andrew", "Pink"), new Person("Bob", "Pink"),
                new Person("Craig", "Pink"), new Person("Daniel", "Pink"),
                new Person("Andrew", "Green"), new Person("Bob", "Green"),
                new Person("Craig", "Green"), new Person("Daniel", "Green"),
                new Person("Andrew", "Orange"), new Person("Bob", "Orange"),
                new Person("Craig", "Orange"), new Person("Daniel", "Orange"),
                new Person("Andrew", "Purple"), new Person("Bob", "Purple"),
                new Person("Craig", "Purple"), new Person("Daniel", "Purple"),
                new Person("Andrew", "Blue"), new Person("Bob", "Blue"),
                new Person("Craig", "Blue"), new Person("Daniel", "Blue")
        );
    }

    private Map<String, List<Person>> personsGroupedByFirstName(List<Person> persons) {
        Map<String, List<Person>> stacks = new HashMap<>();

        int loop = 0;
        for (Person outer : persons) {
            if (!outer.isReachable()) {
                continue;
            }

            String outerFirstName = outer.getFirstName();
            List<Person> stack = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Person inner : persons) {
                loop = loop + 1;
                if (!inner.isReachable()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (isSimilar(outerFirstName, inner.getFirstName())) {
                    inner.setReachable(false);
                    stack.add(inner);
                }
            }

            List<Person> tmp = stacks.get(outerFirstName);
            if (tmp == null) {
                tmp = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            tmp.addAll(stack);
            stacks.put(outerFirstName, tmp);
        }

        System.out.println("Total Loops: " + loop);
        return stacks;
    }

    /*
     * Trivial condition. My actual use case computes the Levenshtein Distance.
     * */
    private boolean isSimilar(String outerFirstName, String outerSecondName) {
        return outerFirstName.equals(outerSecondName);
    }
}

class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String secondName;
    private boolean reachable = true;

    public Person(String firstName, String secondName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }

    public boolean isReachable() {
        return reachable;
    }

    public void setReachable(boolean reachable) {
        this.reachable = reachable;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", secondName='" + secondName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: One optimization you can make: Your inner loop doesn't need to loop over all elements in the list. Just the ones after the one in the outer loop. If your outer loops checks element 1 against 2, 3, 4... etc, then when your outer loops goes to check element 2 you already compared it to element 1 in the previous iteration. So no need to do it again. And of course comparing to itself is quite pointless. So starting the inner loop at the beginning is not necessary and only everything from element 3 is what you care about

Comment: What is this `isReachable()` property? It looks very strange that a query modifies the objects it is processing.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to perform two nested loops at all. Your are grouping by a property, not “comparing each object with each other”. The map which you use to store the result does already remember all encountered objects by the key.

You can simply use

```java
private Map<String, List<Person>> personsGroupedByFirstName(List<Person> persons) {
    Map<String, List<Person>> result = new HashMap<>();

    for(Person p: persons) {
        List<Person> list = result.get(p.getFirstName());
        if(list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            result.put(p.getFirstName(), list);
        }
        list.add(p);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I assumed that this `isReachable()` test was an attempt to optimize your two nested loops and is not part of the actual task.

When you are familiar with lambda expressions, you can simplify this loop further, using a single operation on the map, instead of `get` and `put`:

```java
private Map<String, List<Person>> personsGroupedByFirstName(List<Person> persons) {
    Map<String, List<Person>> result = new HashMap<>();

    for(Person p: persons) {
        List<Person> list
            = result.computeIfAbsent(p.getFirstName(), key -> new ArrayList<>());
        list.add(p);
    }
    return result;
}
```

An equivalent operation using the Stream API would be

```java
private Map<String, List<Person>> personsGroupedByFirstName(List<Person> persons) {
    return persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getFirstName));
}
```

`groupingBy(Person::getFirstName)` is a short-hand for `groupingBy(Person::getFirstName, toList())`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback/comment. Perhaps I wasn't clear in my question. The problem is the "isSimilar" method. In my real use case, I am comparing news headlines and determining whether they are reporting a similar topic. For this I am using the levenshtein distance. Therefore, I can't simply use the object's property as they will be different, but may be similar.

Comment: Well, this code reduces the 28 people of your example to four unique names, so any more expensive analysis can be applied to these four distinct names, which is much cheaper. Indeed, you weren’t clear in your question. The Levenshtein distance is number, not a boolean. Grouping by a distance does not work in general. `[a, b]` might be “similar” (i.e. a distance below the threshold) and `[b, c]` might be similar as well, while `[a, c]` are not. What groups shall the code create?